# Is it possible to use to create Visual Studio solutions from an Azure-hosted web application?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, envdte, azure-web-app-service

I am writing an application that scaffolds the creation of other Visual Studio solutions.  My application is intended to be run on an Azure web app instance and uses C# as the primary middle-tier language.

Previously, I have been able to scaffold or generate VS solutions from a Windows forms app running on my local machine using `EnvDte` and I know it is possible to do the same via a command line.

Is it possible to accomplish to scaffold/generate a Visual Studio solution from my web app that is itself running on an Azure web instance?

Though out-of-scope for the question, please assume that once generated, the solution will be stored in a folder, zipped and emailed to the user, checked into source control, or some other viable option that is altogether a different issue.

Comment: In the case of web app , based on some user triggered event you are doing this scaffolding process right? as long as you can do it on the server side code which could be the same c# code you have already done it should not be an issue. only thing is you have to save the new solution in a blob storage or azure file storage service. storing within web app instance is not advisable as it is not persistent.

Comment: Thanks @Aravind, good comment.